# Redshift User password change permission denied

Tags: aws, redshift

Redshift user not able to change its own password getting below error:

`ALTER USER or_user WITH PASSWORD 'md5<hash>';`

`ERROR:permission denied`

Also tried granting 'ALTER USER' privileges using admin to the or_user.

I have tried the below statement but got an error

`GRANT ALTER USER TO or_user;`

`ERROR: Grant/Revoke system privilege on User is not supported.`

Additionally, I tried creating a role and granting the role 'Alter User' privilege using admin user with below statments:

```
CREATE ROLE some_role;

GRANT ALTER USER TO ROLE some_role;

GRANT ROLE some_role to or_user;
```

and still, or_user is not able to change its own password and throughs an error.

`ERROR:permission denied`

the goal is or_user should be able to change its own password.